# Search with match() through multiple values in an array

Tags: javascript, json, regex, match

I want to get the object as output from which one of the values matches the searched text. I currently do this with return match. But i haven't figured out, how to test for the numbers in the array. Currently it only works if I enter the type or the name.

For example if I enter 2 it should output [{"type":"ABe 8/12", "name":"ZTZ","numbers":["1", "2", "3", "4", "7"]}]

The Json file:

```
[
    {"type":"ABe 8/12", "name":"ZTZ","numbers":["1", "2", "3", "4", "7"]},
    {"type":"ABe 4/16", "name":"STZ","numbers":["5", "6", "8", "9", "12"]},
    {"type":"ABe 4/16", "name":"RTZ", "numbers":["10", "11", "13", "14", "15"]},
    {"type":"Test", "name":"RTZ", "numbers":["16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]}
]
```

The Javascript:

```
const search = document.getElementById('search');

const searchData = async searchText => {
    const res = await fetch('https://cmd-golem.github.io/json/test.json');
    const resJson = await res.json();
    
    let matches = resJson.filter(data => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
        return data.type.match(regex) || data.name.match(regex);
    });

    console.log(matches)
};

search.addEventListener('input', () => searchData(search.value));
```

Does someone know how to do this with return match or if this isn't possible with another way.

```js
const search = document.getElementById('search');

const searchData = async searchText => {
    const res = await fetch('https://cmd-golem.github.io/json/test.json');
    const resJson = await res.json();
    
    let matches = resJson.filter(data => {
        const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
        return data.type.match(regex) || data.name.match(regex);
    });

    console.log(matches)
};

search.addEventListener('input', () => searchData(search.value));
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

Comment: includes or some

Comment: @epascarello And how can i implement includes in my existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion. See the comments.

```js
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const searchData = async searchText => {
    const res = await fetch('https://cmd-golem.github.io/json/test.json');
    const resJson = await res.json();
    const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi'); // note it's ouside the filter.
    // Recursion.
    const found = data => (Array.isArray(data) ? data.find(found) : data.match(regex));
    let matches = resJson.filter(data => (found(data.type) || found(data.name) || found(data.numbers)));
    console.log(matches);
};
search.addEventListener('input', () => searchData(search.value));
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track.  You can search for specific quoted text using something like:

```js
let data = [
  {"type":"ABe 8/12", "name":"ZTZ","numbers":["1", "2", "3", "4", "7"]},
  {"type":"ABe 4/16", "name":"STZ","numbers":["5", "6", "8", "9", "12"]},
  {"type":"ABe 4/16", "name":"RTZ", "numbers":["10", "11", "13", "14", "15"]},
  {"type":"Test", "name":"RTZ", "numbers":["16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]}
];

let filter = "2";
let pattern = new RegExp(`"${filter}"`);
let filtered = data.filter((d) => pattern.test(JSON.stringify(d)));

console.log(filtered);
```

The stringify statement ensures that you have a string for each item, and a RexExp test can test for any match of `filter` in that string

Comment: Note that this will only work if stringify returns a string containing the entire object - any nested custom objects, for example, will be excluded.  If you need to search through those as well, a more thorough search mechanism, like SMAKSS suggests would be required.